# Authorize.Net DPM & Silent post

Tags: php, authorize.net, paypal-ipn, silent-post

Is there any function in Authorize.Net that does the same of the IPN function on Paypal? I've read a lot about Silent Post but I have some of questions.

1. If I have at the moment of paying a Pending status, and after few days Authorize changes it to denied, Is Silent Post going to notify me this status change?
2. Does it work for DPM payment method?
3. Is there any php example code?

I need it very much because I'm doing a project that recharges devices like mobile phones, but in case to have a pending status I have to do this recharge, and if this status is later finally rejected I have to revert this changes, so I need in each moment to know the transaction status changes in Authorize.Net.

Answer (score 2):

Silent Post is essentially Authorize.Net's version of IPN so it is what you're looking for.

> If I have at the moment of paying a Pending status, and after few days Authorize changes it to denied?, is Silent Post going to notify me this status change?

No. Fortunately this rarely ever happens.

> Does it work for DPM payment method?

Yes. It works for all payments regardless of method (DPM< AIM, etc) and status (approved, declined).

> Is there any php example code?

[Handling Authorize.Net Silent Post with PHP](http://www.johnconde.net/blog/handling-authorize-net-silent-post-with-php/) (I am the author of this article)